# Mailer stopped working after switching emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, mailer

A few weeks ago I created a mailer object to send an email whenever a new "Thing" was created. It worked without a hitch, but I then commented out the relevant lines and didn't deal with it for a while. Today I tried it again, and nothing happened. I discovered that the email account I was using had been disconnected for some reason, so I tried it with another email account. Still nothing. Does anyone have a guess for why it might not be doing anything, or how I can debug it? I'm sure the username/password/domain are accurate.

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  user_name: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

**app/mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'username@gmail.com'

  def notify(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email,subject: "Notification")
  end
end
```

**app/views/user_mailer/notify.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def create
  #...
  UserMailer.notify(@user).deliver
end
```

Comment: Do you have a test/spec to verify that the email is sent and the content/attributes are as expected? That is a better way to verify that the mailer function is working; better than trying to manually trigger the email. It might be that the emails are still being sent but some smtp issue locally is suppressing it. Also, does the mailer functionality work on production?

Comment: maybe you have to enable the access to your app in the email config, why don't you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26374624/3851249

Comment: add bang symbol for deliver, and let us know, what is the error? and mails are not going to junk box right..?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I made a button that is supposed to send an email when I press it. I haven't deployed my app yet so I don't know if it works in production.

Comment: @DemiMagus I enabled access to less secure apps, but it's still not doing anything.

Comment: @Nithin What is a bang symbol? No, and there's no activity on the account I'm sending the emails from either: no sent mail or anything.

Comment: @user3739453 this is a bang symbol `!`. I'm assuming that the username is something like "username@gmail.com". Also i see that this is missing for development: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://localhost:3000" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Comment: What would that do? I mean I know it means "not", but what would that accomplish?

Comment: `UserMailer.notify(@user).deliver!`

Comment: @Nithin Oh I see! Now it's telling me that I need to "log in with my web browser and try again".. does that mean log in with the email account I'm trying to send the emails from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'localhost', port: '3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'localhost:3000',
  user_name: 'username@gmail.com',
  password: 'password',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But I don't understand how my code worked before then, if I incorrectly filled in the domain and user_name fields...

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing in development env, add below lines and check
`config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`
`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Comment: Can I add those lines anywhere in my environments/development.rb?

Comment: yes, add these lines where you have access(or scope to access config) variable.

Comment: What should I be checking?

Comment: Trigger the mail and check whether its being delivered or not.you can also trigger mailer method from rails console like UserMailer.notify(@user).

Comment: Okay now I'm really confused. I tried it in the console, and it returned "Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at" ... and then the sentence breaks off. I definitely, definitely wrote the correct username and password though. Do you know what's supposed to come after "Learn more at..." ?