# Rails mailer throws no error, but email doesn't arrive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, mailer

My Rails mailer worked perfectly a few months ago. I didn't deal with it for a long time, and I don't remember changing anything either. But now, no email is sent when I activate the mailer via my console, although I don't receive any errors.

I triple-checked that the email addresses and passwords are correct. I also set up my email according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374624/4534483). But no emails are sent. If something is going wrong, shouldn't I at least be getting an error in my console?

I'm using Rails 4.0.10.

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Website::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'localhost', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'localhost:3000',
    user_name: 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxx',
    password: 'password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

**app/mailers/user_mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "xxxxxx@xxxxx"

  def notify(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email,subject: "subject")
  end
end
```

**Console**

```
$ UserMailer.notify(User.first)
 Rendered user_mailer/notify.html.erb (0.4ms)
=> #<Mail::Message:2623523, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: xxxxxx@xxxxx>, <To: xxxxxxx@xxxxx>, <Subject: subject>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
```

Comment: Can you post the controller action where you are calling the mailer method?

Comment: @Pavan I'm just calling it in my dev console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mailer methods `deliver`,`deliver_now` or `deliver_later` in your `controller` or `Model`

```
UserMailer.notify(User.first).deliver
```

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.10, so I don't think those methods have been introduced yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.deliver_now` or `.deliver_later` on the result of your `notify` method. Check out how to use [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer) for more information.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.10, so I don't think those methods have been introduced yet.